# how to access value hidden elements using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

what i need

- i need to fetch hidden element data according to particular element id.

a.html

```
 <input type="hidden" id="evt_date" value="feb 10">
 <input type="hidden" id="evt_date" value="Mar 21">
 <input type="hidden" id="evt_date" value="april 05">
```

js

```
<script>
        $.each($('input'), function(i, val) {
           if ($(this).attr("type") == "hidden") {
             var event_date = document.getElementById('evt_date');
             console.log(event_date);
           }
        });
</script>
```

problem

- on doing console.log im getting

  ```
    <input type="hidden" id="evt_date" value="feb 10">
  ```
- i want to fetch  all hidden element in loop using js.

updated js code

```
$.each($('input.event_date'),function(i,val)
{
if($(this).attr("type")=="hidden")
{
      console.log(val);
      var evt_date=$('.event_date').val();
      console.log(evt_date);
     $('.date_event').html(evt_date);
 }
 });
```

Comment: Because ID must be unique, in your case you have three identical id - it is mistake

Comment: Do you want the hidden field or its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to use same `id` for multiple element. You can instead use `class` attribute. So first you should change those repeated `id` attributes into 'class' attributes.

***HTML : Updated***

```
<input type="hidden" class="event_date" value="feb 10">
<input type="hidden" class="event_date" value="Mar 21">
<input type="hidden" class="event_date" value="april 05">

<div class="date_event"></div>
<div class="date_event"></div>
<div class="date_event"></div>
```

Next about your answer, loop through the each element and log the value or use it anyway. Try this,

***jQuery :***

`You question seemed little confusing to me when in one part you asked for the data of the element and in another part you asked for the element itself.`

```
$.each($("input[type='hidden'][class='evt_date']"), function(){
    console.log($(this).val()); // value of the element
    console.log($(this)); // the element itself
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/kaf2pfef/)

***Modification of your code :***

***jQuery :***

```
var counter = 0;

$.each($('input.event_date'),function(i,val)
{
    if($(this).attr("type")=="hidden")
    {
          console.log(val);
          var evt_date=$(this).val();
          console.log(evt_date);
        $('.date_event:eq('+ counter +')').append(evt_date);
        counter++;
     }
 });
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/mk17Lasn/)

Comment: console.log(val.value);
        
         $('.date_event').html(val.value); im only getting  april 05 appaneded

Comment: i have tried:   $('.date_event').append(val.value).eq();

Comment: o/p: after this Feb 10 Mar 10 Mar 21 Mar 26 • like this but i need to appnd feb 10 in one  div march 10  in another div .....and so on...

Comment: in short i could say append data in single div i need to appnd in another div

Comment: @user4041461, use `:eq()` selector and change it's index. Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same id for all the inputs. The id should be unique. Use a class instead

```
$.each($('input.evt_date'),function(i, field) {
    if($(this).attr("type")=="hidden") {
        console.log(field);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('input'),function(i,val){
    if($(this).attr("type")=="hidden"){
        console.log($(this).val());
     }
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y46h6ute/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why you used same **Id** but this will be the short way:

```
$("input [id='evt_date'][type='hidden']").each(function(){
   console.log($( this ))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(index,item){
 console.log($(item));
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t55xLc55/)